# Moto G System update installation

Tags: updates, motorola-moto-g2

I've downloaded a system update and now i'am freak out.

I downloaded new update on my phone by going to About Phone/System update 
and when it finish downloading it ask installation and I click yes. The phone power off itself and restarted in to a team win recovery project screen and it is has eight options.

1. install
2. wipe
3. backup
4. restore
5. mount
6. settings
7. advance
8. reboot

What should I do now ?

I click on install option and it asking for a zip/image file but i cannot find anywhere in my phone.

Comment: The OTA update probably expects OEM's recovery to do the flashing. Remove TWRP, flash the stock recovery, download the OTA update again and see what happens.

Comment: I try to update because the system pop up msg several time saying there is a new update but its too complicated.  I don't what to do I gave up. Anyway Thanks.